# How to add functionality to a searchview, to search in already Pre-pupolated database of room database in a fragment?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, fragment, searchview

I'm learning to make a  medicine  (drug ) dictionary app to store medicine names and their farther information. My app contains a main activity and three fragment. Fragment host is located in the main xml which host my other fragments. In my home/start fragment  a button exist which by pressing that the user navigated to medicinelistfragment which contains a recycleveiw that displays the medicines names stored as already pre-packaged database in assets folder. The recycleveiw is populated from already pre-packaged database stored in assets folder and the data displayed in recycleveiw. I want to search this data and by entering of a query user can see results of the query he/she has submitted. I have implemented search wegat in actinbar and it's clickable but when I click and inter same thing nothing happens. My project is approximately  similar to android developer training teams, Room and Flow codelabe,  I use this codelabe as template to make this app. the only deferences that  I want to implement search functionality in the medicineWlistfragment which contains Recycleveiw.

Room and Flow codelabe https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-5-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow#0

I have tried several ways to get succeed but not worked. I want to search data from room database in medicinewlistfragment but when  I click search waged nothing happens.
This is the main activity

````
```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity( ) {
 lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

 private lateinit var navController: NavController

 private lateinit var toolbar : Toolbar

 private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView

 private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

 private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
 private lateinit var listener : 
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 setContentView(binding.root)

 toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_Toolbar)
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

 navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_v)

 val bNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bnv)

 val novController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
 bNavigationView.setupWithNavController(novController)

 drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
  appBarConfiguration =
AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.settingFragment,R.id.aboutFragment),drawerLayout)
     setupActionBarWithNavController(novController,drawerLayout)
 navigationView.setupWithNavController(novController)

 val navHomeFragment = 
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as 
NavHostFragment

 var navController = navHomeFragment.navController

 setupActionBarWithNavController(novController)

 }
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
 val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)

 return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
 || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
 }
}
````

This is my medicinWlistFrament:

````
```

   
class MedicinwListFragment : 
Fragment(R.layout.fragment_medicinw_list),MenuProvider,SearchView.OnQueryText
Listener {

 private var _binding: FragmentMedicinwListBinding? = null
 private val binding get() = _binding!!

 private lateinit var medicineNameAdapter: MedicineNameAdapter

 private val viewModel: MedicineTableVeiwmodel by activityViewModels {
 MedicineTableVeiwmodel.MedicineNameViewModelFactory(
 (activity?.application as 
MedicineTableApplication).database.medicineDao())
 }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 }
 override fun onCreateView(
 inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
 savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
 ): View {
 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 _binding = FragmentMedicinwListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, 
false)
 val view = binding.root

 val menuHost : MenuHost = requireActivity()
 
menuHost.addMenuProvider(this,viewLifecycleOwner,Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
 medicineNameAdapter = MedicineNameAdapter { }
 setHasOptionsMenu(true)
 return view
 }

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

 val recyclerview = binding.recyclerView
 recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

 val medicineNameAdapter = MedicineNameAdapter {
 val action = MedicinwListFragmentDirections
 .actionMedicinwListFragmentToMedinformationf(
 medicineName = it.medicineName
 )

 view.findNavController().navigate(action)

 }
 recyclerview.adapter = medicineNameAdapter
 lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
 viewModel.fulMedicine().collect() {
 medicineNameAdapter.submitList(it)
 }
 }
 }

 override fun onDestroyView() {
 super.onDestroyView()
 _binding = null
 }

 override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
 menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.medicine_list_f_menu,menu)
 val mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
 val msearchView = mSearch.actionView as SearchView
 msearchView.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
 msearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
 }

 override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
 return true
 }

 override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
 if (query != null){
 searchDatabase(query)
 }
 return true

 }
 override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
 if (newText != null){
 searchDatabase(newText)
 }
 return true
 }

 fun searchDatabase(query: String?){
 val searchQuery = "%$query%"
 viewModel.searcheMedicine(searchQuery).observe(this, { list ->
 medicineNameAdapter.submitList(list)
 })
 }
}
```
````

This is my entity:

````
```
@Entity(tableName = "medicine")
data class Medicine(
@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) var id: Int ,
@NotNull @ColumnInfo(name = "medicine_Name") var medicineName: String ,
@NotNull @ColumnInfo(name = "medicine_Info") var medicineInfo: String ,
)
```
````

This is my Dao

````
```
@Dao
interface MedicineDao {

 @Query("SELECT * FROM Medicine ORDER BY medicine_Name ASC")
 fun getAll() :kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow <List<Medicine>>

 @Query("SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE medicine_Name = :medicineName ORDER 
BY medicine_Info ASC")
 fun getByMedicinname( medicineName: String) : 
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow <List<Medicine>>

 @Query("SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE medicine_Name LIKE :searchQuery")
 fun searchMedicine(searchQuery : String?) : LiveData <List<Medicine>>
}
```
````

My viewModel class

````
```
class MedicineTableVeiwmodel (var medicineDao: MedicineDao): ViewModel() {

 fun fulMedicine(): Flow <List<Medicine>> = medicineDao.getAll()

 fun medicineForMedicinname(name: String) :Flow <List<Medicine>> = 
medicineDao.getByMedicinname(name)

 fun searcheMedicine(searchQuery:String) : LiveData<List<Medicine>> = 
medicineDao.searchMedicine(searchQuery)

 class MedicineNameViewModelFactory(var medicineDao: MedicineDao): 
ViewModelProvider.Factory{

 override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
 if 
(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MedicineTableVeiwmodel::class.java)){

 @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
 return MedicineTableVeiwmodel(medicineDao) as T
 }
 throw IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN viewModel class")
 }
 }
} 
```
````

This is my search menu item

````
```
type <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item
 android:id="@+id/menu_search"
 android:title="@string/search"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
 android:iconTint="@color/white"
 app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
 tools:targetApi="o" />
</menu>
```

`
````

I'm not know that where  is the problem in my code  but I  guess the problem may be in initialization of viewModel or msdicineNameAdopter  in medicinewlistfragment.

I hope you understand what I expected and what is obstacle in the way of my success.

Please help me to solve this problem and point out me in correct direction. I appreciate  anyone advice and assistance. Thanks